# How can you shut down an embedded jetty instance?

Tags: java, service, jenkins, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have an embedded jetty project that builds a single .jar file that starts up our webapp.

```
public static void main(String[] args){            
            final Server server = new Server(threadPool);
            //Do config/setup code for servlets/database/contexts/connectors/etc
            server.start();
            server.dumpStdErr();
            server.join();
}
```

So while this works great to start our server by calling *java -jar MyApp.jar* I am at a loss for a way to stop it.  This is especially annoying when I want to stop the server via our build server.

When we used the Jetty service and deployed a .war file we could do this:

1. Build latest .war file via Jenkins
2. Stop Jetty service via shell *(sudo service jetty stop)*
3. Overwrite old .war file in **/opt/jetty/webapp** with new .war file
4. Start Jetty service via shell *(sudo service jetty start)*

I currently have two ideas:

1. Create a servlet that calls server.stop() if you have a secret get parameter specified.  Use curl on the shell in Jekins to hit this servlet.
2. Use something like Apache-Commons daemon wrapper to make my app into a service.

Is there some obvious mechanism I am missing to stop the server?

Comment: does sending a kill to the process work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`ShutdownHandler`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ShutdownHandler.html)

The server side:

```java
Server server = new Server(8080);
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]
{ someOtherHandler, new ShutdownHandler("secret password", false, true) });
server.setHandler(handlers);
server.start();
```

The client side (to issue shutdown).

```java
public static void attemptShutdown(int port, String shutdownCookie) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:" + port + "/shutdown?token=" + shutdownCookie);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.getResponseCode();
        logger.info("Shutting down " + url + ": " + connection.getResponseMessage());
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        logger.debug("Not running");
        // Okay - the server is not running
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried this with Jetty 10.0.9, but I'm not getting any response from the ShutdownHandler, I mean, the getResponseCode method just keeps waiting and never ends. The handler seems to be there because if I omit it the getResponseMessage returns NotFound. I tried also by curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/shutdown?token=secret and postman or using a wrong password with the same result. Any clue or idea?

Comment: I set breakpoints inside Server and ShutdownHandler but they were never reached when I sent the request from Postman and it never throws a timeout. I just realize that if I set the sentShutdownAtStart argument in ShutdownHandler equals true then the server connector is not started, that's why the shutdown requests were not attended by the server. I don't know if it is a bug but it is really annoying to not receive any error or warning by using such a trivial thing as a constructor argument.